# How to modify this script to account for different case?

Tags: vba, excel, string-comparison

I wrote a VBA script which searches for a string in one column and returns the match in another column. The point is match an item number to it's product image by SKU. The problem is that it fails if the case of the item number and the image have different case. The script is below:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim NA As Long, NC As Long, v As String, I As Long, J As Long
    Dim v2 As String
    NA = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    NC = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    For I = 2 To NA
        v = Cells(I, "A").Value
        v2 = ""
        For J = 2 To NC
            If InStr(Cells(J, "C").Value, v) > 0 Then
                v2 = v2 & ";" & Cells(J, "C").Value
            End If
        Next J
        Cells(I, "A").Offset(0, 1).Value = Mid(v2,2)
    Next I
End Sub
```

How can I account for different case? Is there a method for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty simple, just cast it to lower case:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim NA As Long, NC As Long, v As String, I As Long, J As Long
    Dim v2 As String
    NA = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    NC = Cells(Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    For I = 2 To NA
        v = LCase(Cells(I, "A").Value)
        v2 = ""
        For J = 2 To NC
            If InStr(LCase(Cells(J, "C").Value), v) > 0 Then
                v2 = v2 & ";" & Cells(J, "C").Value
            End If
        Next J
        Cells(I, "A").Offset(0, 1).Value = Mid(v2,2)
    Next I
End Sub
```

I just took your code sample and put casts to lower case on `v` and `Cells(J, "C").Value`.

I didn't test this, so I can't guarantee flawless functionality.

---

You can also alter your module (on top) with

`Option Compare Text`

That will shut down case sensitivity completely (so you wouldn't need `LCase(..)`)

Comment: I added another possibility in the end of the answer

Comment: It's a bit dangerous and confusing to use `Option Compare Text` because it affects the entire module. That may not be desirable. Still, both of your solutions should work. +1

Comment: @RubberDuck correct. I was assuming that there are no other Subs or Functions in that module. Good point in highlighting it though.

Comment: I'd also add a suggestion to use the $ version of the functions whenever possible.  They run a little faster than the non$ version of the same function.  e.g.  If InStr(LCase$(Cells(J, "C").value, v) > 0 Then

Comment: I had to accept this answer because it came first, sorry @RubberDuck!

Comment: @Bitter I gave RubberDuck an upvote, too. So his effort won't be in vain :)

Answer (score 1):

Just use the `vbTextCompare` option of the [`Instr` function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264811.aspx).

```
If InStr(1, Cells(J, "C").Value, v, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
    v2 = v2 & ";" & Cells(J, "C").Value
End If
```

> [vbTextCompare] Performs a text comparison, based on a case-insensitive text sort order determined by your application's current culture information.

Comment: You're welcome! I know you don't have the rep to upvote yet, but please be sure to upvote useful answers. It's how we show our appreciation around here.

Comment: I forgot about optional arguments in InStr, so this should conclude the list of possible solutions :)

Comment: @RubberDuck: Hmm .. I'm getting a type mismatch error on the if condition. Any thoughts?